# Python program becoming unstable after multiple simulations

Tags: python, oop, debugging, tkinter

I apologize if this has an easy answer, but I have been searching everywhere and trying everything I could think of to solve this problem to no avail.

Basically I have a differential equation solver that simulates heat flow in a plate, and every time I click a Tkinter button, I would like to run a fresh simulation/animation. The problem is that the program tends to become unstable after multiple calls for new simulations.

I knew something was awry when I allowed the user to specify whether an animation would loop continuously. If an animation was allowed to loop, subsequent simulations (looping or not) would slow down and the CPU would remain loaded as if the animation was still looping somewhere in the background after it should have been replaced with the new one.

Here are the relevant portions of my code, please let me know if I'm doing something dumb.

```
class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.print_button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Run Simulation',
                                      command=self.run).grid()

    def run(self):
        simulation = HeatSim(self)
        simulation.compute(self)
        simulation.animate(self)

class HeatSim(GUI):
    def __init__(self,gui):
        # Initialize variables here

    def compute(self,gui):
        # Compute values of data matrix

    def animate(self,gui):
        frames = 100

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        # Canvas used to display the animation embedded within a tkinter window
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=gui.root)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()

        images = []

        for i in range(frames):
            im = ax.imshow(data[:,:,i],cmap='hot',animated=True)
            images.append([im])

        anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,images,interval=0,blit=True,
                                         repeat=0)

        canvas.show()

# Main program loop
root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *unstable*?